# how to trigger ng-dblclick by using "Enter" keyboard button in angular JS 1.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, accessibility, wai-aria

I want access my application by using keyboard. I have included **angular-aria.js** to make the application accisibility. But **dblclick** is not triggered when I enter twice from the keyboard.

the code snippet in my page:

```
     <div class="data-details-block-row" data-ng-class="{'selected': selectedJobQueue == jobQueue}" data-ng-repeat="jobQueue in jobQueueList" >
    <a href="javascript: void(0);" role="button" data-ng-click="toggleSelection(jobQueue)" data-ng-dblclick="showJobQueueInfo(jobQueue, $event);">
        Ranjan
    </a>
</div>
```

I have addedd **data-ng-keypress="($event.keyCode === 13 || $event.keyCode === 32) && showJobQueueInfo(jobQueue, $event);"** but also it won't worked.

```
    <div class="data-details-block-row" data-ng-class="{'selected': selectedJobQueue == jobQueue}" data-ng-repeat="jobQueue in jobQueueList" >
    <a href="javascript: void(0);" role="button" data-ng-click="toggleSelection(jobQueue)" data-ng-dblclick="showJobQueueInfo(jobQueue, $event);" data-ng-keypress="($event.keyCode === 13 || $event.keyCode === 32) && showJobQueueInfo(jobQueue, $event);">
        Ranjan
    </a>
</div>
```